# Unable to build docker image with error "shim error: docker-runc not installed on system"

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am trying to build a docker image from a Dockerfile but seeing error `shim error: docker-runc not installed on system`

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential \
    && apt-get install -y libssl-dev libbz2-dev

$  docker build -t ub .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu
 ---> 6a2f32de169d
Step 2 : RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y build-essential     && apt-get install -y libssl-dev libbz2-dev
 ---> Running in b7574a066f82
shim error: docker-runc not installed on system
```

Docker version details:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:         1.12.6
 API version:     1.24
 Package version: docker-common-1.12.6-16.sl7.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.7.4
 Git commit:      3a094bd/1.12.6
 Built:           Fri Apr 14 09:57:15 2017
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.12.6
 API version:     1.24
 Package version: docker-common-1.12.6-16.sl7.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.7.4
 Git commit:      3a094bd/1.12.6
 Built:           Fri Apr 14 09:57:15 2017
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
```

docker info:

```
$ docker info
Containers: 11
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 11
Images: 5
Server Version: 1.12.6
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-8:2-526997-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 856.8 MB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 7.817 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 1.479 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.146 GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.135-RHEL7 (2016-11-16)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: seccomp
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-229.20.1.el7.x86_64
Operating System: Scientific Linux 7.3 (Nitrogen)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
Number of Docker Hooks: 2
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.641 GiB
Name: caspgval4
ID: RM5S:3ZWP:VPDC:AFOP:V3PA:XW4B:DMRS:VCB2:Q22K:3GBX:UYZO:EBAK
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Registries: docker.io (secure)
```

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26022

Comment: Dint get any solution from the link.

Comment: I don't think you go through all of them

Comment: Please update the question with `docker version` and `docker info`.

Comment: Updated the question with required details.

Answer (score 1):

Your install of docker appears to be missing some required parts. There may have been an error on your install, or the Scientific Linux install may have issues with their install. You can try to upgrade to the release direct from docker rather than using the version from Scientific Linux with the following command run as root:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Comment: It doesn't work, `$ curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh

  Either your platform is not easily detectable, is not supported by this
  installer script (yet - PRs welcome! [hack/install.sh]), or does not yet have
  a package for Docker.  Please visit the following URL for more detailed
  installation instructions:

    https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/`